# Module import precedence in Pyinstaller program

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pyinstaller

I am trying to have an easy way to update a program I am working on, by being able to just place replacement .py files in a folder which I then put at the top of the sys.path list so all import statements will first check that folder and not my top level directory, importing the newer .py files and not the ones used to build the program originally with PyInstaller.  Right now, if I use this code:

```
    import sys,os
    bundlePath = 'c:/tests/importTest' 
    print ("Bundle path: {}".format(bundlePath))
    importPath = bundlePath + '/uploads'
    sys.path.insert(0,importPath)
    print ("Import path: {}".format(sys.path[0]))
    os.chdir(sys.path[0])
    import testyTastery
    print(testyTastery.message)
```

My Python IDE or running this script through the command line will print the message from `uploads/testyTastery.py` (there is also a testyTastery.py in the top level directory).  However, when I change line 2 to `bundlePath = sys.path[1]` (because builds in PyInstaller put the top level directory in sys.path[1], at least in Windows, sys.path[0] points to a base_library.zip that PyInstaller creates) and build this into a folder bundle for PyInstaller (making sure to either copy `uploads/testyTastery.py` or include it in the `.spec` file), I get the message from the testyTastery.py script, not the uploads/testyTastery.py script.

Any idea on how to easily change this?  To be clear, the first two print statements result in the same output for both running it before and after compiling with PyInstaller, after changing the second line as mentioned.

I don't know, but maybe it has something to do with PyInstaller always looking at files it packages before looking in sys.path for imports?

Edit:  To be clear, if I do a build with none of the files available, then put the files in the appropriate folders afterward, the import precedence is just like in the command line / IDE.  This suggests to me that files packaged by PyInstaller are higher up in the import hierarchy.

Comment: If you are building as `--onedir` you can run `pyinstaller` to generate the updated .pyd files and copy and replace the old ones. Just make sure that this works before distributing the "patch".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I am sure it will come in handy for others and perhaps myself in the future.  

I am looking for a way to push updates with the least amount of data as possible, and your suggestion would mean about 10mb of data for an update versus 1-100kb, which adds up very quickly especially with the way I plan on distributing the updates (as direct transfers through ØMQ).

Comment: If you are not concerned about the fact that the code is exposed to the user, you can replace the .pyd with the .py or .pyc file. It still works.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to this problem.  To be clear, the original problem was to package up files (in folder option) with PyInstaller, and later just drop in files to replace the ones that were originally packed up.  Because PyInstaller inserts its method of loading files into sys.meta_path, you need to install your own custom import method before PyInstaller's.  Here is what I've got (changing the order of system path is because PyInstaller also changes sys.path[0] to a zip file, sys.path[1] is what you really want to be at the top of the sys.path chain if you are doing this or using sys.path[0] in your program:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = [sys.path[1]] + [sys.path[0]] + sys.path[2:]
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

class MyImporter(object):
    def find_module(self, module_name, package_path):
        print ('entered again')
        if os.path.exists("{}/{}.py".format(sys.path[0],module_name)):
            return SourceFileLoader(module_name,"{}/{}.py".format(sys.path[0],module_name))
        else:
            return None
    def load_module(self, module_name):
        if os.path.exists("{}/{}.py".format(sys.path[0],module_name)):
            return SourceFileLoader(module_name,"{}/{}.py".format(sys.path[0],module_name)).load_module()
        else:
            return None
sys.meta_path.insert(1,MyImporter())
```

If you do this in your main file that PyInstaller imports then your entire program will search sys.path[0] (It would be trivial to add more folders to your system path and search them as well, of course) before searching for PyInstaller packaged modules.